# added two decimals in assembly, but result is hexadecimal

Tags: assembly, hex, decimal, addition

Hi I simply want to add two decimals in assembly like:

```
org 1000  

mov ax,08H
mov bx,05H

add bx,ax
hlt
```

But the result in bx register is **000D**, I want to see in the register **0013**(decimal). More interesting thing is when I try same code with higher numbers I can get decimal result:

```
org 1000  

mov ax,52H
mov bx,12H

add bx,ax
hlt
```

After compiling second code, I see **0064** in bx register, but with first code the result is written as hexadecimal. How can i solve this

Thanks

Comment: Err... both outputs are displayed in hex representation.

Comment: but in hexadecimal notation 52+12 should not be 64!!

Comment: @Soyaslan You are wrong; `0x52 + 0x12 = 0x64`.  You see, when you specify `52H`, that means "I am specifying a ***hexadecimal*** literal with value 52 (in hex)."  That's what the `H` means.

Comment: so how can i add two decimals? when i try to remove "h" at the end, it still gives the result as hexadecimal. i dont want to see hexadecimal i want 8+5=13 not "0D"

Comment: If you must, refer to your assembler/debugger documentation re: 'output representation base', (or something like that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your first problem you should place the sum in the AL register.

```
mov bl,8
mov al,5
add al,bl
aaa
aad 16  ; --> AL contains 0013(decimal)
```

The second problem can be solved by first calculating the tenths (storing the AL in an extra register), then calculating the units, and then combining both with another `aad 16`.

If your assembler doesn't *know* the instruction `aad 16` you can substitute it with `db 0D5h,10h`

I overlooked a much better solution that will work for both problems!

```
mov bl,8
mov al,5
add al,bl
daa    ; --> AL contains 0013(decimal) CF=0

mov bl,52h
mov al,12h
add al,bl
daa    ; --> AL contains 0064(decimal) CF=0

mov bl,52h
mov al,19h
add al,bl
daa    ; --> AL contains 0071(decimal) CF=0

mov bl,52h
mov al,59h
add al,bl
daa    ; --> AL contains 0011(decimal) CF=1 --> 0111(decimal)
```